# Magic system involving contracts with a mysterious being

Tags: internal-consistency, magic, gods, balancing-magic-systems, low-fantasy

I am planning a series of fantasy novels, want to make sure my worldbuilding makes sense. I will focus on the magic system for now but I do think that some basic context of what kind of story I am aiming for is appropriate:

It will revolve around a cast of complex characters composed of a well-intentioned necromancer with grand ambitions and his close friends/allies as they systematically gain power through political conspiracies, schemes, warfare, strategizing etc., with the goal being the creation of a better world and the uncovering of truths behind the setting. During the series, they find a lot of opposition from various individuals and factions with their own philosophies and motivations, including an oligarchic council of magicians that govern the affairs of magic users on a global scale. The characters of the main cast also have their own differences, psychological issues and relationship difficulties that will influence their quest for a better world and create a lot of character-based conflict, which will be a key driving force of the plot.

### Magic system

The magic-system revolves around a god that bestows its magical powers upon those who seek it out and are deemed worthy. This worthiness and the exact nature of the magical powers, as well as their limits are based on the rather nebulous "plan" of the god. The god is in some way the source of the magical powers and he allows access to segments of it to various people through the signing of a psychic pact. In order to have a chance of signing such a pact, one must embark on an arduous, dangerous adventure to one of the 7(?) caves where direct psychic contact with the god is possible. The journey leads through sparsely populated territory inhabited by dangerous creatures and bandits and characterized by difficult, barren terrain. There's also territorial competition over these areas. Few people have the means to survive such an endeavor, or the bravery and willpower, and of those that do, quite a few either receive weak or specialized powers or none at all.

The lack of knowledge on magic and the nature of the setting give ground to experimentation => new, innovative methods, combat tactics based on the logic behind the powers, and a lot of truth-seeking by some characters.

All magic is limited and influenced by the will of the god who, using his control over the source of magic, ensures that the causality of the setting abides by some nebulous vision. This might sound like Deus Ex Machina, and it kind of is. But this is not the only reason for this rule: it also, in my mind, makes a lot of sense, especially in the context of certain details of the setting. In addition, it is kind of neccessary due to just how game-breaking magical powers would be if freely unleashed. They require a limit to preserve causality and balance, and so that the ways the magicians use their powers are more interesting when they have to use logic, innovation, strategy and collaboration in order to overcome obstacles in clever ways. Magic's power's limited by the imagination and smarts of magicians and balancing limits imposed by the God.

All magical powers are based on the most defining virtues of their user => all magic is fundamentally good, no magic users purely evil. All powers are capable of both good and evil and the way in which they are used depend on the user, who could be driven towards evil actions due to understandable, human reasons.
The powers gained from a pact with the god are individual, but tend to fit neatly into man-made pattern-based categories with slight variations, e.g. necromancers who raise skeletons. Magic has limits that have to be worked within or around in order to accomplish goals.
List of types:

1. Necromancy: Reviving dead souls and regenerating their dead bodies. The "healing" is limited to what's neccessary for the dead bodies to function. Decay of the brain means that necromancers revive the soul, but not the whole mind, and in the process, (have to) impose a programming on their zombies that allows them to manipulate/control them. And skeletons have lost their whole brains, their bodies are moved by magic itself.
   Considered "dark" magic, subject to discrimination or even persecution, one of the most rare types.
2. Pyrokinesis/Temperature Manipulation: Pyromancers conjure and manipulate fire, but can also lower temperatures. The latter however requires methods that are in conflict with personality tendencies that lead to the user having this power to begin with.
3. Telekinesis: Manipulating matter with the mind. In theory, ridiculously overpowered because of the implications of its potential uses, but the god imposes limits on telekinesis due to this, and this magic is hard to master due to the enormous mental effort required to manipulate objects in this way, especially when modern physics and science are not sufficiently available as a guidance.
   Rarest type by far, viewed with great scepticism.
4. Mind manipulation: A broad category of magical powers revolving around reading minds and feelings and manipulating them.
5. "Wuenschling"/"Wishling": This pact allows its user to request wishes to be granted by the god that the god may or may not fulfill. The number of wishes is usually 3 but can vary, and sometimes wishes can be gained through various circumstances.
6. Seer: Has access to an invisible, phase-shifting avatar that allows the user to sense things from afar supernaturally. Possibility to view the future through collaboration with a Chronomancer.
   Rare, considered a light power and encouraged as a solely good power despite the Orwellian potential.
7. Healing: Can cure injuries and even diseases. Knowledge of biology, anatomy and medicine improve the healers abilities.
   Most common type of magic, considered light but frequently used for torture and human experimentation by some.
8. Greenheart: Influences living non-humans, usually limited to certain types of creatures based on personality.
   Considered light but can be used to weaponize creatures, including dragons, which are devastating in ways akin to nuclear weapons. This would cause massive global political and social upheaval if achieved, but research on this is difficult.
9. Witch: Broad category that encompasses those whose pacts give them powers to manipulate poison, neurochemicals (to seduce, manipulate or harm), diseases (spread or cure), and/or create fate-twisting curses/wishes. Often need to attain ingredients for their magic.
10. Spellbreaking: They do not have magic of their own, but they can negate the magic of others, as a projected negation field, an immunity or through rituals or physical contact. Usually fairly specialized, such as its users generating anti-teleportation fields which allow the council of magicians and other powerful factions to protect themselves from attacks.
    Seemingly harmless power that is considered light and is one of the most common powers.
11. Chronomancy: Can ac/decelerate time. Rarely, they can reverse time or even time-travel. The massive limits imposed because of its causality-breaking potential are well-known, so if a Chronomancer manages to go against them, it gives them infos on fate or the intentions of god, which will become relevant in the search for the truth.
12. Alchemy/Enchanting: Can manipulate matter through rituals and bestow magical traits upon objects. Mostly limited by their imagination and resources.

Additionally, due to the individualized nature of the pacts, there's potential for super-rare, unheard-of abilities, such as precognition or thaumaturgy. These would make for potential antagonists or otherwise disruptive forces. Also, certain characters are intended to undergo changes that, in addition to the discovery of new ways to use their powers, will turn them into potentially very threatening people.

So, how many magicians are there?
That's a tough one. Should be rare, but common enough for frequent magicians in major armies, and for there to be magician factions keeping each other in check. The world shouldn't be competed over solely by magicians, but rather by many different people, with magicians being one type. Charismatic politicians, powerful noblepeople, cunning military leaders, ingenious inventors, etc. are all forces to be reckoned with as well who can be as threatening as most magicians. And factions that compete for power should be a mix of types of people, magicians being the most prominent and powerful, but also most targeted and not self-sufficient.
Regarding the employment of magicians in the military: I want them to be more akin to the way very powerful weapons/units are used. Warfare shouldn't always rely on or involve magicians, but the constant possibility of magic will influence strategies and keep commanders on edge. Also warfare is supposed to be shifting due to new innovations in magic use and growing use of muskets and cannons and the invention of steam power.

World population: in the range of 600 million to 1 billion people, the EU-like "multinational" kingdom has at most 150 million inhabitants.

### My questions

Considering what I am aiming for and the setting, what would be a realistic frequency of magicians? How would this magic system and the magicians impact this world, or rather what are aspects I will have to keep in mind regarding the way this society works?

Clarification: I am concerned that this story is at risk of having worldbuilding issues that take the reader out of the story because crucial implications of this magic system could be missing. I want to avoid this, obviously, so I am looking for guidance from people who are more experienced and knowledgeable than me, be it because they read a lot of fantasy fiction or because they write it themselves.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't think this is quite a worldbuilding question, it's a story question. The question of 'How many' is for you, the author, to decide. It's a bit too broad and a bit too opinion based. A question such as 'These are the numbers of each time, what will be the likely result given a specific circumstance', is much better.Consider breaking this question up into smaller chunks.

Comment: Well it's a question about how this magic system would affect its world, which I think is worldbuilding-related. Perhaps I worded my questions poorly, I also cut out a lot of clarifications because of the char limit that didn't allow me to post. I will edit the post to improve the wording of the question.

Comment: You say that whether someone is magic or not is up to the will of some deity.  There's no mechanic here for us to figure out, it's just the whim of some god.  How are we supposed to figure out how many people he blesses?

Comment: I don't recall that it is normal for a magic system to have mechanics that allow precise calculations like that. I am just hoping for a realistic approximation. I am also more interested in what would be the effects on the economy, politics etc. if this magic system was in place and widely known and I wanted to turn here for guidance from people who have more experience, be it from writing fantasy fiction or reading a lot of it, because I think that I am at risk of writing a story where magic exists in this manner, but crucial implications of it are missing, leading to worldbuilding issues.

Comment: I don't understand how this is a story question. I am not asking about the story. But without a story for the world to be set in, there is no world. Without a book, there is no world. So, obviously, it is the story that I am concerned could have worldbuilding issues. That doesn't mean I am asking about the story. I am asking for advice about the world is story is set in, specifically about how this world would be affected by the magic system. Obviously, the worldbuilding will affect the story, and the story will affect the worldbuilding. That doesn't make this a story question. I don't get it.

Comment: Your query is "how many magicians are there in the world" and there is nothing in the world that will dictate that. It's only related to plot and themes you want to explore. So, it's story-based. You want magic to be very tough or undesirable? Perhaps a burden? Then few people will be obtaining it. If you want the opposite - magic to be good, desirable, and perhaps easy, then you'd have many mages. Perhaps about 1 in 10 possesses magic, which means you'd bump into them as you are taking a walk. That's all theme related and convey the intention you have behind the magic system.

Comment: Okay. Thank you. I will move on to the next aspect then. Maybe something will come up later during other questions I have about the setting, and I do have this post to provide context when neccessary.

Answer (score 2):

**As you need for your story.**

> During the series, they find a lot of opposition from various individuals and factions with their own philosophies and motivations, including an oligarchic council of magicians that govern the affairs of magic users on a global scale.

When your characters encounter individuals or groups of individuals, there will often be one or more than one magic users among them.  Magic users in the larger world do not concern your story except as color; your thief character for example might make reference to what they did with magic in her old town, which is why and other had to leave.

You have put thought into your magic system.  Now use that to spice up the individuals and factions they encounter.  I envision the council as being the running plot and each of the various encounters like a show within a TV series which occurs within the larger running plot.

Answer (score 1):

Flip the question. **What is the deity/deities getting out of this equation?**

They will want to offer precisely as many contracts as suits their needs. No more, no Less.

A god of war may go on a magician forging spree to drum up war, or support a war effort. Presumably the presence of or need for war is the benefit to such a god.

A god of healing will offer to the right sort of people, or when epidemics are about to/already happening. Presumably the act of healing, or removing disease is the reward to such a god.

As to how powerful a mage could be would be capped by the total amount of power the god has. Presumably this surges and wanes with the number of followers, and the amount that the god has already "supplied" to alive contractors. Perhaps a reserve of unspent energy earnt over the centuries for a rainy day.

That could give us a rough calculation: `600 000 000 people * 1 faith per person / 1000 faith per average mage = 600 000 average mages max.`

You can play with the faith budget. Perhaps the world is very pious and get 2.6 faith per person (maybe there are a lot of unbelievers). Maybe average mages cost 2000 faith. Maybe the gods are at war and are using up their power reserves. Maybe the gods are hoarding their energies right now.

Comment: The god has access to all the magical powers and more and doesn't depend on faith or magicians for maintenance. No supply issue: every person who seeks out a pact and is deemed worthy personality-wise is given powers, there is virtually no upper limit. The true intentions of the god I don't want to mention here because it is a huge reveal. He's certainly benefitting from the pacts though, but the characters don't know how, although the nature of the meddling suggests it has something to do with causality and fate. A major aspect of the plot is the search for the truth behind all of this.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I liked your idea. It doesn't apply to my setting, but it was a good thought IMO and it gave me a better idea on how to approach this. :)